# Bernoulli trial coin flip problem

Tags: probability

> A coin is biased so that the probability of heads is $2/3$. What is the
>   probability that exactly four heads come up if the coin is flipped seven
>   times, assuming the flips are independent?

To solve this I just applied the Bernoulli Trial formula
$$P={7\choose 4}\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^4\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^3 = 0.256\ldots$$

However the answer seems to be the following:
$$P={7\choose 4}\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^4\bigg(\frac{1}{3}\bigg)^3 -\frac{35\cdot 16}{2187} - \frac{560}{2187}$$

Why is that? It seemed like a standard Bernoulli trial problem to me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if the minuses in the 'official solution' should be equal signs.

Comment: I think that's a problem, because it's a pdf file maybe they got the characters wrong. Anyway as long as my solution is correct, Thank you!

Comment: The answers (yours and theirs) agree if it's equal signs.

Comment: If minus signs were correct, then this probability would be negative.